# Python+SQLAlchemy: Getting mapper class from InstrumentedList?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I want to dynamically get the SQLAlchemy mapper class that instances of InstrumentedList use.

I have a 1-M ParentClass-ChildClass (let's call the column myRelation), and the parentInstance.myRelation are InstrumentedList instances. I could hack it and grab the class of the first instance in InstrumentedList, but this doesn't work if there are no objects in the InstrumentedList.

The reason: I need to append a Python dictionary containing the properties of mapper class X to the InstrumentedList, but I don't know the mapper class at runtime. Since I can't append a dict, I need to get the mapper class.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the relationship is associated with the instrumented list via `property`.  so start with this plain vanilla mapping:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = "a"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    bs = relationship("B")

class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = "b"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('a.id'))
```

in any recent version of SQLAlchemy you can see it like this:

```
print A.bs.property.mapper.class_
```

in 0.8 there's a little more API available and you can do this:

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect
print inspect(A.bs).mapper.class_
```

docs for inspect-> http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/inspection.html

docs for "mapper->class_" -> http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/mapper_config.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper.class_

Comment: Your answer was absolutely helpful, however I found that you can in newer SQLAlchemy (1.x) do A.bs.mapper.class_ (at least for my relationship definition it works)